# CSS styles overridden - selector not specific enough?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Styles from a CSS class are not applied (overridden by other selector). How can I fix it?

HTML:

```
<body class="expertmode">
  <div id="gallery">
    <img class="appearing">
    <img class="appearing">
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```css
#gallery {...}
.expertmode #gallery {...}
#gallery img {...}
.expertmode #gallery img {...}
.appearing {...}
```

**Problem:** styles from the class `.appearing` get overridden by styles from `.expertmode #gallery img`. I don't want that. How can I make the styles from `.appearing` have higher priority?

**More info:**

- `.appearing` is a class that is first applied to new images when they are inserted in the gallery and then removed (javascript), in order to trigger a CSS3 transition that makes the images slide in nicely. The class seems to be working, because if I set properties in the `.appearing` selector which are not also present in the other selector, they are properly appied to the images.
- `.expertmode` is a class that the `body` can either have or not have. It doesn't matter for this problem, I just cannot get rid of it.

Comment: You can always use `something: 200px !important;` to overwrite more specific selectors. But you have to consider the problems with editing the css later. Anyway you can read more here: http://james.padolsey.com/usability/dont-use-important/

Comment: Hint: use a specificity calculator like http://specificity.keegan.st/ (enter in the selectors you want to compare then click "Sort by specificity")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this to add new styles to the standard img properties

```
.expertmode #gallery img.appearing {...}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! I had tried almost the same before, but with an addional space between img and the dot. That did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Use !important directive. For example

```
.appearing {color: navy !important;}
```

The !important rule is a way to make your CSS cascade but also have the rules you feel are most crucial always be applied. A rule that has the !important property will always be applied no matter where that rule appears in the CSS document. So if you wanted to make sure that a property always applied, you would add the !important property. However, this is absolutely a last resort. It is better to create your styles in more structured way.

Comment: ahh! please don't use `!important` unless you absolutely must!

Comment: No need to downvote, this is an answer. But @mrangry777 lacks to explain the problems with `!important`